# function not writing to text file

Tags: python, text

I'm trying to make a sort of logbook in a text file to avoid re-doing efforts. I have the following function that perform this task:

```py
def write_to_logbook(target_name):

   with open('C:\Documents\logbook.txt', 'a+') as f:
      for lines in f:
          if target_name not in lines:
              f.write(target_name + '\n')
              f.close() #when I didn't have f.close() here, it also wasn't writing to the txt file
```

When I check the text file after I run the script, it remains empty. I'm not sure why.

I call it as such (in reality target name is pulled down from a unique ID, but since I don't want to put everything here, this is the gist):

```py
target_name = 'abc123'
write_to_logbook(target_name)
```

Comment: Were there any errors running the code? Maybe your full code has some problems that aren't letting it work?

Comment: You said the file "remains empty" - does that mean the file is empty to begin with? In that case, it's no surprise that nothing happens - you are trying to iterate over the lines in a file which has no lines. Is it possible that what you actually want to do is read from one file and write to another? Also, I wouldn't explicitly call 'file.close()' inside the 'with' block.

Comment: Closing the file in the middle of the loop is absolutely wrong. You don't need to close the file explicitly, as the `with` statement takes care of that.

Comment: @12944qwerty no there were no errors, which is why I wasn't sure why it's not working. It's not called in any other loops either, so it shouldn't affect that. I've tried to debug with print statements and they all print.

user10987432 im just trying to store ID numbers in a text doc. not reading and writing from multiple files, just using the one file to store a history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted. I used chepner's solution as a jumping off point, since it didn't exactly work (only wrote one `target_name` for some reason) and kind of did a hybrid of the two:

```py
def write_to_logbook(target_name):
    fname = 'filepath'

    with open(fname) as f:
        for lines in f:
            if target_name in lines:
                return

    with open(fname, 'a+') as f:
        f.write(target_name + '\n')
```

Thanks for the solution, it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to (potentially) read the entire file before you can decide if `target_name` has to be added to the file.

```
def write_to_logbook(target_name):
    fname = r'C:\Documents\logbook.txt')

    with open(fname) as f:
        if any(target_name in line for line in f):
            return

    with open(fname, 'a') as f:
        print(target_name, file=f)
```

`any` will return `True` as soon as any line containing `target_name` is found, at which point the function itself will return.

If the target name isn't found after reading the entire file, then the second `with` statement will append the target name to the file.